# Is 'sleep' based on the system clock or on time elapsed?

Tags: linux, osx, sleep

Is 'sleep' based on the system clock or on time elapsed?

For example, if you execute:

```
sleep 1200
```

And immediately suspend your system for 10 minutes, will it end in another 10 minutes, or will it continue to wait for the full 20 minutes?

Comment: I don't think suspending the system affects the system clock like that; perhaps a direct change of time would be a better example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I guess it was easy enough to test.  After initiating a 5 minute sleep, I suspended the system for about 2 minutes.  The answer?

Sleep is calculated using elapsed time of the process, not clock time.

```
date; sleep 300; date
Tue Jul  2 20:58:41 EDT 2019
Tue Jul  2 21:05:28 EDT 2019
```

This may have been predictable since man sleep(3) says:

> System activity may lengthen the sleep by an indeterminate amount.

Which kind of implies the amount of time is internal to the sleep process.